# Why does getting JDBC Connection need Reflection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, reflection

The code as following:

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("no class!");
}
```

why geting Connection by JDBC need `Class.forName()`: the Reflection mechanism？Can `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` replace it？

Comment: The basic answer is that you don't, since 2007. The correct term is 'Reflection', not 'reflex'.

Comment: sorry，I am weak at English.

Comment: All the more reason why you should stick to the actual words used rather than translating them back and forth.